# How to recode a continuous variable into Ranges

Tags: r

I need to recode a continuous variable into categories, usually i use the "cut" Function, but in the cut function i need to specify the breaks. i am looking for a way to have a different set of breaks depending on other categorical variables in my data frame.

the variable in my example is Cost and the "breaks" are in the second table "cost.range", i have a different set of Breaks for each "Region" and each "Category"

Example :

```
Region    Product     Category Cost
Country A Product 1     CAT A  731
Country B Product 1     CAT A  659
Country C Product 1     CAT A  385
Country D Product 1     CAT A  763
Country A Product 2     CAT A  701
Country B Product 2     CAT A  759
Country C Product 2     CAT A  580
Country D Product 2     CAT A  147
Country A Product 3     CAT B  645
Country B Product 3     CAT B  657
Country C Product 3     CAT B  424


Region       Category  Cost.Range      Range
Country A      CAT A         10          R1
Country A      CAT A         50          R2
Country A      CAT A        200          R3
Country A      CAT A       1000          R4
Country A      CAT B         20          R1
Country A      CAT B        100          R2
Country A      CAT B        400          R3
Country A      CAT B       1500          R4
```

code to generate the example :

```
Region <- c("Country A","Country B","Country C","Country D","Country A","Country B","Country C","Country D","Country A","Country B","Country C","Country D","Country A","Country B","Country C","Country D")
Product <- c("Product 1","Product 1","Product 1","Product 1","Product 2","Product 2","Product 2","Product 2","Product 3","Product 3","Product 3","Product 3","Product 4","Product 4","Product 4","Product 4")
Category <- c("CAT A","CAT A","CAT A","CAT A","CAT A","CAT A","CAT A","CAT A","CAT B","CAT B","CAT B","CAT B","CAT B","CAT B","CAT B","CAT B")
Cost <- c(731,659,385,763,701,759,580,147,645,657,424,34,850,463,160,550)

Table1 <- data.frame(Region, Product, Category, Cost)

Region <- c("Country A","Country A","Country A","Country A","Country A","Country A","Country A","Country A")
Category <- c("CAT A","CAT A","CAT A","CAT A","CAT B","CAT B","CAT B","CAT B")
Cost.range <- c(10,50,200,1000,20,100,400,1500)
Range <- c("R1","R1","R3","R4","R1","R2","R3","R4")

Table2 <- data.frame(Region, Category, Cost.range, Range)
```

Comment: You can use `by` which will also work on each Category at a time. Can you provide your data in a copypastable form and the code you've tried?

Comment: thank you, I edited my post to include the code, i looked into the "by" documentation, since i am new to R i do not see exactly how to use it. could you please explain ?

Comment: I thought I'd use `cut`, but labels are not unique in Range column. Is this by design?

Comment: yes that is why i cannot use cut, i have 50 categories and 20 countries with different ranges.

Comment: Different range is not a problem, non-uniqueness of the labels is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant solution (and I'd be interested to see a better method) but it should achieve the result you're looking for.

The `select()` and `distinct()` functions from the `dplyr` package find the possible combinations of `Region` and `Category`. These combinations are used to subset the two tables and apply the `cut()` function to each subset.

```
library('dplyr')
library('data.table')

dt1 <- data.table(Table1)
dt2 <- data.table(Table2)

t2d <- Table2 %>% select(Region, Category) %>% distinct

for(i in 1:nrow(t2d)){
  dt2_range_subset <- dt2[Region == as.character(t2d$Region[i]) 
                          & Category == t2d$Category[i], Cost.range]
  dt1[Region == as.character(t2d$Region[i]) & Category == t2d$Category[i],
      Cost_factor := cut(as.matrix(Cost), dt2_range_subset)]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, would it be possible to have the Range column from the Table2 in the result ( R2 ) and not the bins like  (100,800] ?

Comment: It is, but the implementation depends on your desired behaviour (which is why it's important to include this in your question). As currently formatted the output will produce three ranges (e.g. for Region A Cat A you'll get (10, 50], (50, 200] and (200, 1000]) but you've got four labels to apply.

Comment: i was not clear in my question sorry, the R1 should apply up to the corresponding range for example [0, 10] -> R1 , (10, 50] -> R2 , (50, 200] -> R3 , (200, 1000]) -> R4

Comment: I did some testing, unfortunately this solution works for small data sets but my real dataset contains 11 million rows and i do not have enough memory to use this solution.